# PHP date - 86400 * 7 weekday - monday isn't always a monday?

Tags: php, date

I'm really curious why output of this short code isn't always the same weekday?

How come at one of days it flips from monday to sunday? When i use `strtotime('+1 week', $t);` it works as expected.

thank you for explanation!

```
<?php

            $t = strtotime('2016-09-19');
            for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
                echo date('w', $t)."\n";
                $t += 86400 * 7;     
            }

?>
```

Comment: It works fine for me: https://eval.in/641298

Comment: ok so apparently the problem is daylight saving time. Prior to PHP 5.1 the output was 'correct' (same day).

Answer (score 2):

Because you're adding hours, and you're using a timezone with daylight saving time. When you hit November 6th, DST sets in, and the day shows the previous day. Set your timezone to UTC, or use `+1 day` instead of hours.